# Manga where a woman assumed to be cursed was actually a saintess or a god's chosen

Tags: story-identification, manga

Read this manga a couple months ago on firemanga or bato.

**Characters:**

Main character: A woman/teen who has been assumed to be a cursed one. She actually wasn't cursed and was a god's chosen? Or something like that. She pretends to be insane and assumes her water spirit to be the only true family she has.

King of another country: When the main character gets married to a man from this other country, the king seems to know that she possesses a spirit/elemental. The king also seems to know a lot more about her and might actually be a spirit himself?

**Story:**

There has been a severe drought for a long time in her homeland/kingdom. The royalty of said kingdom just pinned every problem on her. Later, she gets married off to a nobleman in another kingdom and pretends to be insane.

She wishes for revenge and her water spirit actually encourages her to take it, while the king of this other kingdom strongly recommends her to think again.

Comment: I think I read this, but I don't recall anything about her acting insane. It may have just been a different "married off because she's useless, but is actually super powerful" manga. Do you recall if there was a scene where she bathes/enters a spring in her new husband's country and this awakens or massively strengthens her powers?

Comment: @qazmlpok I don't think there was a scene like that but I remember her visiting a lake of sorts and teleporting to there from a drought ridden town.

Comment: Probably a different story, then. In the first chapter, is she about to be sacrificed to end this drought, but does her future husband show up suddenly and save her? (and then it rains). Also, do you remember if this was black&white or full color?

Comment: @qazmlpok Thank you for your time but answer was found before I got back to you. Still if you remember this manga you thought might have been what I were looking for could you post it's name here? It also sounds something I would like.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to find it again. It was also two different stories - the first has the MC be seemingly useless but is married off, and while on the trip towards his homeland (or in his homeland) they stop at a spring or similar and she awakens her powers. That was unrelated to the 2nd, where the MC is to be literally sacrificed, but stopped by a sudden suitor. The first is definitely a manga; I think the 2nd was a manhwa.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is ***[The Princess in the Attic](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/anf45yp/the-princess-in-the-attic)***.

> Branded as a cursed child, Princess Osiria spent most of her life locked in an attic. In actuality, Osiria is the divinely chosen, the one who could’ve saved the empire of Trionfo. Instead, she was sold to a neighboring kingdom and left in the care of Sir Fedelius, a handsome young knight. Although her heart beats faster when Fedelius is around, she doesn’t plan on staying for long. She wants only one thing...to get revenge on those who abused her and killed her mother. Will her heart soften with love or will she seek vengeance to the very end?

The main character, Osiria's, birth coincided with the start of a drought in the empire of Trionfo. Her mother, who'd conceived Osiria with the emperor, was blamed for the drought by the high priest, labelled a witch and executed by way of a guillotine. Just before the blade fell, she angrily cursed everyone around her and threatened that if a drop of Osiria's blood was spilled, the empire would meet its demise.

The empire had wanted to execute Osiria as well, but fearing the consequences of doing so, they locked her in an attic instead. Unbeknownst to them, Osiria was one of the rare individuals born periodically who was divinely chosen by the gods. She has a divine crest on her right hand that's invisible to most people, and could a summon a water spirit named Aqua, who was her only friend and teacher while she was locked away. She kept her powers hidden from everyone else, and pretended to be crazy and stupid so that they'd underestimate her.

Twenty years after Osiria was locked away, the empire decided to clean her up and send her to the neighbouring kingdom of Jardin as a diplomatic hostage, in exchange for Jardin selling them water at a low price. When Osiria arrived in Jardin, she was brought before the king there, and feigned mental incompetence, hoping this would cause him to lose any romantic interest in her. However, when he looked at her, she sensed something odd about him, as if he could see the crest on her hand that was invisible to everyone else, and wondered if he was human.

She was placed in the care of a knight, but continued to pretend that she was crazy, and secretly made plans with Aqua to escape and take revenge against the empire of Trionfo. She would sometimes sneak out at night, and in one instance, visited a village in Trionfo by teleporting there through a pond. When she met the king of Jardin for a second time, he revealed that he knew about her water spirit and her plans for revenge, and advised her against that course of action.

This manhwa is available to read at [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/the-princess-in-the-attic/info). There's also a trailer for it on YouTube.

Comment: II saw this post and read the story. Really disappointed by the plot holes . They say the blessed one is born once in a hundred years but all the assassins after the FL imply the next blessed one will be born if she dies and she's barely 20yrs. What's their plan for the next 80 years ‍♀️